# Most readable way to add elements to Java vararg call

Tags: java, variadic-functions

If I have a method `public void foo(Object... x)`, I can call it in this way:

```
Object[] bar = ...;
foo(bar);
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
Object baz = ...;
Object[] bar = ...;
foo(baz, bar);
```

Obviously, it can be done by creating an array with size 1 greater than `bar` and copying `baz` and the contents of `bar` there. But is there some more readable shortcut?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a varargs method with an additional argument from a varargs method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293989/how-to-call-a-varargs-method-with-an-additional-argument-from-a-varargs-method)

Comment: @Raedwald From http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286720/old-own-question-flagged-as-duplicated-of-new-own-question: "It's perfectly acceptable for an older question to be closed as a duplicate of a newer one if the newer one has better answers than the older one." I don't think the answers there are better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guava's [`ObjectArrays`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html) class provides methods to concatenate a single object to the beginning or end of an array, largely for this purpose.  There's no way to get around the linear overhead, but it's already built and tested for you.

Comment: Good point on using Guava, although I'd like to see the `concat(...)` methods provide varargs parameters. :)

Comment: I believe that `concat(T[], T[], Class<T>)` is the closest type-safe option possible.

Comment: Specifically, since generics and varargs don't play well together in Java 6 (which Guava still targets), it's awkward.  I think it _should_ be safe enough in Java 7 to annotate such a method with @SafeVarargs, but it's not quite safe yet to say.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's not out-of-the-box way to make that more readable.

However, you could create a helper method that would take an array and a vargs parameter and returns the array with the varargs appended.

Something like this:

```
public T[] append(T[] originalArray, T... additionalElements) { ... }

foo( append( bar, baz) );
```

Comment: Clever; and I disagree with "there's not out-of-box way to make more readable" -- you just did! :)

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be to overload `foo()`:

```
public void foo(Object... x) {}
public void foo(Object[] a, Object... x) {}
```