# How to call a varargs method with an additional argument from a varargs method

Tags: java, delegates, variadic-functions

I have some varargs system function, where T is some actual type, like `String`:

```
sys(T... args)
```

I want to create own function, which delegates to the system function. My function is *also* a varargs function. I want to pass through all the arguments for my function through to the system function, plus an additional trailing argument. Something like this:

```
myfunc(T... args) {
    T myobj = new T();
    sys(args, myobj); // <- of course, here error.
}
```

How do I need to change the line with the error?
Now I see only one way: create array with dimension [args] + 1 and copy all items to the new array.
But maybe there exists a more simple way?

Comment: @aioobe, actual object type, otherwise, if I right, I can't create myobj. Some change first message

Comment: That was why I was asking ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Now I see only one way: create array with dimension [args] + 1 and copy all items to new array.*

There is no simpler way. You need to create a new array and include `myobj` as last element of the array.

```
String[] args2 = Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length + 1);
args2[args2.length-1] = myobj;
sys(args2);
```

If you happen to depend on Apache Commons Lang you can do

```
sys(ArrayUtils.add(args, myobj));
```

or Guava

```
sys(ObjectArrays.concat(args, myobj));
```

Answer (score 6):

You may call `sys()` twice if the order doesn't care:

```
T myobj=new T();
sys(myobj);
sys(args);
```

If you can't use this, switch to collections (eg. LinkedList) for all of your functions.

Comment: I can't todo this call, because sys back some another object as result, depended from input params. For example: string.format().

Comment: Then you must copy the array or use collections for all those functions. Then you can add your new item.

Comment: @brummfondel, are you suggesting that he should modify the argument collection? That's not very polite to the caller (and only works if the argument is a mutable collection).

Comment: @aioobe You may implement several variants of the function, one with varargs, one with List. Finally, one will call the other. But you'll have a fexible API.

Comment: I'd say that just clutters the API. Use libraries to Apache Commons or let the caller deal with it.

Comment: Well, it depends on several things: If you need a small memory foodprint and performance using a complex converting library is a bad idea. If this doesn't care, use it and keep your APIs small.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), then you can do:

```
sys(ObjectArrays.concat(myobj, args))
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 solution:

```
sys(Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(args), Stream.of(myobj)).toArray(T[]::new));
```